# On heap/stack and OS page swapping

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, paging, elf

I am trying to understand few linux-related concepts 
Can anyone help me answer the following questions.

**[Question I]** 
I am aware that the compiler gives Virtual Address (VA) for a program's data and code segment. The OS uses these VA's and try to fit them into physical memory. This is what ELF loader (fs/binfmt_elf.c in source code) does in linux. When does the VA for stack and heap gets allocated for a process? I guess its dynamic, but from where does the VA come for those segments? If possible, can anyone point me to source codes.

**[Question II]**
While I know that, physical memory is limited in size. Hence the OS has to swap out pages at times to keep several processes running. When it needs to swap out a page, it pulls the page from memory and writes it into disk. I completely agree that data and code pages can be written into disk (perhaps they get written back in the same area where they came from disk). But can the OS swap out the heap and stack pages as well? If yes, where will it store in disk?

Comment: One question per question, please. Multiple-question posts are not well-suited to our format.

Comment: These are very much related questions, hence posted them together. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Question I:

You need to start with a simplified view. For question 1, think about it in terms of logical memory rather than virtual memory. Let's say we are doing this in 32bit mode, you will have a theoretical maximum of 3/4ths of 2^32 logical memory available to your process.

When your new process loads an executable, that entire address space is going to be null. By that I mean there is no memory at all (conceptually). The program loader will then read the instructions in the executable file to build the logical address space at the start of execution.

The loader will create a user stack. You've got to have one for the program to run. By that, I mean that the loader will allocate logical pages for the stack.

The loader will probably not create a heap. There will be an address range for the heap but the loader will probably not map pages to it. You can explicitly map pages using system calls to create pages for your own heap. Alternatively, you can call a library function like malloc() that will map pages for you.

Question II:

All user pages can be swapped out, including heap and stack. They go to the page file, which on Linux is a swap partition.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I as understand the heap address ranges are already prepared while loading but will be mapped to physical memory upon request (say mmap/brk etc). If possible, can anyone provide snippets of where these address ranges for heap are prepared (not mapped yet) while loading ?

Answer (score 1):

1.) In load_elf_binary

```
850         /* Do this so that we can load the interpreter, if need be.  We will
851            change some of these later */
852         retval = setup_arg_pages(bprm, randomize_stack_top(STACK_TOP),
853                                  executable_stack);
```

2.) In swap partition / file

Comment: Any comments/pointers on understanding those arguments to setup_arg_page() ? What about heap address ranges?

Comment: Heap is set in set_brk. Actually, the parameters are mostly self explainable. What is your purpose of knowing this and asking your question?

Comment: My purpose is to get a deeper understanding of linux (mostly loaders). I know the strace output could be a simpler way of finding heap begin (i.e. brk(0) return value), but really curious from where this address and stack range show up for every process.

Comment: Actually, as user3344003 said,  the Linux code is not a good point to start, because it is complicated and overloaded by different functionality. To understand how use environments works, and how OS load / manage them i recommend you this lab http://pdosnew.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/labs/lab3/